# How to prove that limit cycle can exist in 2D curl field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I know limit cycle can definitely exist in a 2D curl field (that is field with no divergence, $\nabla \cdot F = 0$), but how to explicitly construct such an example? Kind of stuck where to start. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just take the circular motion $\dot x=-y$, $\dot y=x$. So all trajectories are circles, however,  no limit cycles in the "graphical sense".

Comment: Thanks! But I was trying to show that limit cycle can exist rather than cannot exist.

Comment: Yes, and every trajectory is its own limit cycle, the whole phase portrait is nothing but limit cycles up to the equilibrium at the origin. I'm not sure if one can get asymptotically stable limit cycles, as when following a converging spiral the phase volume shrinks in radial direction, so it would have to stretch in the angular direction. So the closer the spiral gets to the limit cycle, the faster it has to go. Of course the speed can not go to infinity, the vector field should at least be continuous, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limit cycle cannot exist in a 2D curl vector field. A 2D curl vector field is a hamiltonain vector field and as such it has a first integral, so if you have at least one closed curve trajectory, then there will be a whole smooth foliation of closed curve trajectories in an open neighbourhood of the given closed curve trajectory.

Indeed, let the vector field in question is $$X \, =\, P(x, y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, +\, Q(x, y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ assume the $\gamma_0$ is a closed curve trajectory tangent to the vector field, i.e. $\gamma_0$ is the trajectory of a periodic solution of  the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dx}{dt} \, =\, P(x, y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} \, =\, Q(x, y)$$
We assume that the vector field $X$ is smooth and well defined in a large enough open domain in the plane that contains $\gamma_0$. Now, $\gamma_0$ is a smooth embedded submanifold of the plane, diffeomorphic to the unit circle, and it bounds a simply connected closed compact domain $K(\gamma_0)$ which is diffeomorphic to the closed unit disc. Let us take a small enough neighbourhood $D(\gamma_0)$ of $K(\gamma_0)$, diffeomorphic to an open disc of the plane. Then the vector field $X$ is smooth and well defined on the this simply connected open domain $D(\gamma_0)$ and $\gamma_0 \, \subset \, D(\gamma_0)$. So from now on all arguments will take place in $D(\gamma_0)$.

Define the smooth differential one form
$$\omega \, = \,  - \,Q(x, y)\,dx \, +\, P(x, y)\, dy$$ and observe that $$\omega(X) \equiv 0$$ Now,
\begin{align}
d\omega \, &=\, d \Big(-Q(x, y)\,dx \, +\, P(x, y)\, dy \,\Big) 
\, =\,   - \, \,dQ(x, y)\wedge dx \, +\, dP(x, y)\wedge dy \\
&= -\, \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}(x, y)\, dy \wedge dx \, +\, \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x, y)\, dx  \wedge dy\\
&= \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}(x, y)\, dx \wedge dy \, +\, \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x, y)\, dx  \wedge dy \\
&= \left( \, \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}(x, y)\, dx\, + \, \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x, y)\right) dx  \wedge dy \\&\equiv 0
\end{align}
Since $D(\gamma_0)$ is simply connected, more precisely it deformation retracts onto a point, there exists a smooth function $f(x, y)$ defined at least on $D(\gamma_0)$ such that
$$df\, =\, \omega$$
Hence,
$$P(x, y) \, =\, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)$$
$$Q(x, y) \, =\, -\, \frac{\partial f}{\partial  x}(x, y)$$
which means that the original vector field can be written as
$$X \, =\, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, - \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial  x}(x, y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
and is therefore hamiltonian with first-integral (hamiltonian) $f(x, y)$ so every trajectory in the domain $D(\gamma_0)$ follows a level curve of the function $f$, i.e.
$$f(x, y) = c$$ for some constant $c$.
Since $\gamma_0 \, \subset \, f(x, y) = c_0$, then the trajectories of the vector field $X$ in a small enough tubular neighbourhood of $\gamma_0$ are also closed curve trajectories.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that there can be no limit cycle. Perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: I am glad you found my answer useful.